# Why my String is not deleted if I remove it from my textfield?

Tags: angular, string, frontend, backend

I have a text box where I write something, if I do a search for it it does it and it works fine.
But if I delete it, the String remains "saved" and gives an error when searching, there is no empty space, the previous String is still there.

Any solution?
Thanks! :D

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="nombreendpoint">{{ "registro.nombre" | translate }}</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="nombre" id="name" class="form-control" (keyup)="onKey($event)" (change)="onChange(registerForm.value)" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.nombre.errors }" />
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.nombre.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.nombre.errors.required">Nombre es requerido</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ngbTooltip="{{ 'registro.busqueda' | translate }}"
            [disabled]="disablebutton"
            (click)="onSubmit(registerForm.value)">
      {{ "registro.busqueda" | translate }}
    </button>
```

---

```
onSubmit(evt: any) {

    this.disablebutton = true;
    let valorBusqueda = '';
    let idbusqueda = Object.create(Object.prototype);
    Object.keys(evt).forEach(function (key) {
        if (evt[key] !== null && evt[key].length > 0) {
            if (valorBusqueda.length > 0) {
                valorBusqueda += ', ';
            }
            valorBusqueda += evt[key];
            idbusqueda = key;
        }
    });
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        this.textobusqueda = valorBusqueda;
        this.registro.getFilterEndpoint(evt, valorBusqueda);
        this.submitted = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.resultados = true;
            this.registro.verResultados = true;
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.disablebutton = false;
        }, 2000);
    }
    if (evt.id === null && evt.aplicacion === null && evt.nombre === null) {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContentAlert);
        modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'Hay que seleccionar un campo del formulario';
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: your question in unclear. Please provide some more context and part of your HTML / Typescript code

Comment: *Where* do you "search"? *Where* does it remain *saved"? *Where* does it give an error?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear... Okay:

I have a text box /
I'm looking for something "Example" /
I hit the search button /
It does well /
Delete "Example" /
I hit search and it gives an error. /
But if, for example, I reload the page and try to search, it won't let me do it because the field can't be empty.

Comment: Can you please provide your TS and HTML code?

Comment: Yes i did it in post

Comment: @Meet actually means your full code of `html` and `ts` . I understand that your form remember latest value from the previous action and the form is disappear by somehow and then your form logic is cracked. For now, you code that given wasn't enough to told what happen.